# Nav drawer doesn't show all items from arrays.xml in Espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso

I'm creating an espresso test for an app, in this particular test case verifying that all open source licenses used are displayed correctly in order in a nav drawer window in the information section of our app. See attached screenshot. They are defined as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <array name="open_source_library_names">
    <item>GSON</item>
    <item>JNBIS</item>
    <item>ZXing</item>
    <item>ZXing Android Embedded</item>
    <item>CERT-CVC</item>
    <item>JJ2000</item>
    <item>JMRTD</item>
    <item>SCUBA</item>
    <item>Bouncy Castle</item>
  </array>
```

As you can see from the attached screenshot they are displayed correctly.

I have defined my Espresso test as such:

```
@Test
public void clickLicensesOpensNewNavWindow() {
  mainActivityScenario.onActivity(activity -> {
    activity.findViewById(R.id.info).performClick();
    onView(withId(R.id.nav_licenses)).perform(click());
    onView(allOf(withId(R.id.nav_licenses_header), withText(R.string.licenses))).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    onView(withText(R.string.licenses_text)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));

    //verify that all licenses are shown
    String[] urls = activity.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.open_source_library_names);
    for (String s : urls) {
      onView(withText(s)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    }
  });
}
```

It finds all the particular licenses used except the last 2 ones, and the test fails at the first-to-last item "SCUBA". What can cause this to be apparant in Espresso but not in real use case? Here is the (partial) stacktrace:

```
No views in hierarchy found matching: an instance of android.widget.TextView and view.getText() with or without transformation to match: is "SCUBA"
If the target view is not part of the view hierarchy, you may need to use Espresso.onData to load it from one of the following AdapterViews:android.widget.ListView{221ef142 VFED.VC.. ......ID 0,0-320,470 #7f0a0112 app:id/lv_licenses}

View Hierarchy:
...
...
+---------->View{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=320, height=1, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@54e80296, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=138.0} 
|
+--------->RelativeLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=320, height=48, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams@4065bc80, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=155.0, child-count=2} 
|
+---------->AppCompatTextView{id=2131362356, res-name=tvText, visibility=VISIBLE, width=4, height=48, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams@540deaa8, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=16.0, y=0.0, text=GSON, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false} 
|
+---------->AppCompatImageView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=24, height=24, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams@3b65a336, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=280.0, y=12.0} 
|
+--------->RelativeLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=320, height=48, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams@446659c2, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=203.0, child-count=2} 
|
+---------->AppCompatTextView{id=2131362356, res-name=tvText, visibility=VISIBLE, width=5, height=48, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams@520c2e6b, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=16.0, y=0.0, text=JNBIS, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false} 
|
+---------->AppCompatImageView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=24, height=24, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams@c610478, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=280.0, y=12.0} 
|
+--------->RelativeLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=320, height=48, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams@1b85f33d, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=251.0, child-count=2} 
|
+---------->AppCompatTextView{id=2131362356, res-name=tvText, visibility=VISIBLE, width=5, height=48, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams@1f4376f1, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=16.0, y=0.0, text=ZXing, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false} 
|
+---------->AppCompatImageView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=24, height=24, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams@79995c7c, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=280.0, y=12.0} 
|
+--------->RelativeLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=320, height=48, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams@2e16cf6d, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=299.0, child-count=2} 
|
+---------->AppCompatTextView{id=2131362356, res-name=tvText, visibility=VISIBLE, width=22, height=48, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams@1ddf0c6f, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=16.0, y=0.0, text=ZXing Android Embedded, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false} 
|
+---------->AppCompatImageView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=24, height=24, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams@755fbbd9, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=280.0, y=12.0} 
|
+--------->RelativeLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=320, height=48, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams@1408e333, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=347.0, child-count=2} 
|
+---------->AppCompatTextView{id=2131362356, res-name=tvText, visibility=VISIBLE, width=8, height=48, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams@1c011318, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=16.0, y=0.0, text=CERT-CVC, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false} 
|
+---------->AppCompatImageView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=24, height=24, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams@527ca176, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=280.0, y=12.0} 
|
+--------->RelativeLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=320, height=48, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams@6d32cd75, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=395.0, child-count=2} 
|
+---------->AppCompatTextView{id=2131362356, res-name=tvText, visibility=VISIBLE, width=6, height=48, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams@5af2a6b4, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=16.0, y=0.0, text=JJ2000, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false} 
|
+---------->AppCompatImageView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=24, height=24, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams@1ff6eb63, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=280.0, y=12.0} 
|
+--------->RelativeLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=320, height=48, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams@2e22b182, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=443.0, child-count=2} 
|
+---------->AppCompatTextView{id=2131362356, res-name=tvText, visibility=VISIBLE, width=5, height=48, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams@6a7ead6, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=16.0, y=0.0, text=JMRTD, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false} 
|
+---------->AppCompatImageView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=24, height=24, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams@5eed8ba5, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=280.0, y=12.0} 
androidx.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: an instance of android.widget.TextView and view.getText() with or without transformation to match: is "SCUBA"
If the target view is not part of the view hierarchy, you may need to use Espresso.onData to load it from one of the following AdapterViews:android.widget.ListView{221ef142 VFED.VC.. ......ID 0,0-320,470 #7f0a0112 app:id/lv_licenses}
```

[image]

Comment: For ListView testing, it's recommended to use `onData` instead of `onView`. Since ListView create list item on demand, it's very likely that the views for "SCUBA" or "Bouncy Castle" are not created yet if they are off-screen. https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/lists

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer. I was unaware of `onData()` for listviews.